# How to interpret a Current Value into a PWM signal percentage?

Tags: current, pwm, matlab

I have a maltab model, output of which (from an RL circuit) is a value for current. I want to interpret this value of current into a PWM signal with frequency of 1000Hz and duty cycle of 50%. I have only worked with defined pwm signals with constant frequency & duty cycle. 
so basically the system should be like this:

RL CKT - Current(0.5A) --> PWM signal generator_output = 0.5A @ 1000Hz & 50% Duty Cycle

Thanks for any form of guidance!

Comment: Are you asking what facilities there are in matlab to take an analogue value and convert it to a pulse width?

Comment: preferably with matlab but it will also be great to know how it is done in principle!

Comment: Are you saying you want to use PWM to create a signal that has an average current of 0.5A or are you saying that the peak current of the PWM is 0.5A and you want the average to be some other value? By the way, PWM with a fixed frequency and duty cycle is not PWM...there's no 'M'.

Comment: I am sorry for the insufficient info, i need the signal to have peak value of 0.5A(amplitude). As for modulation, I will keep changing the Peak Value. This current value from the RL Matlab block system depends on other variables. As i change them, the current value changes between the 0-1.1 amps.

Comment: I thought for a few seconds I knew what you wanted but now I'm lost again.

Comment: -1 Please clarify. You said "i need the signal to have peak value of 0.5A...I will keep changing the Peak Value". When you talk about "the current" make it very clear whether you are referring to the peak current or the average current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question and subsequent comments, what you are asking for is a pulse with a repetition rate of 1000 Hz and a duty cycle of 50% whose amplitude is a linear function of the current from your RC circuit.  First of all, if the shape is a pulse and the duty cycle is 50%, then the waveform is a square wave.  Second, if you want the amplitude to vary with your current, then that is amplitude and not pulse width modulation, also known as PAM.  Third, it should be easy to create such a waveform within MATLAB by defining a function with the characteristics you want.

Comment: THANK YOU for explaining something i had misunderstood! i will add with more specifications!